# Mask Email-To-Case From Address

Tags: email2case

I have on demand email-to-case setup and working in Salesforce. When the agent responds to the case, the `from` address shows the email service address. I've modified the email layout to include both the `from` and `from address` fields. So, the agent can clear the `from address` field and select the friendly support email address that is used to forward to the email service address. I don't believe there is a way to default the friendly support email address into the `from` address field and automatically clear the `from address` field. Ideally I'd like to remove the `from address` field from the layout to avoid having the agent have to clear it because you cannot send the email with both the `from` field and `from address` field populated. I'm trying to provide a way for the agents to not have to clear and select the correct email to put into the `from` address field and handle automatically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Set the Organization-Wide Email Addresses.

KB article here: [Default 'From' address in Email-to-Case](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213688&type=1)